# Where i can find the proof of Ostrowski theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Where i can find any proof of next theorem?

Theorem of Ostrowski: Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence 1, which is analytically continuable beyond unit disk. Then the power series is overconvergent if it possesses Hadamard-Ostrowski gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, in the book by P. Dienes, The Taylor series, Dover, NY, 1957.
In German: in the original A. Ostrowski's paper.

Comment: @Alexandre, Can you give a reference for the Ostrowski paper?